# Mooc Fi Loop Confusion

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve Mooc.fi Exercise 103, which is to: design a database for a birdwatcher. It contains name and latin name of birds, as well as number of times observed. I'm having issues understanding why the two codes below result in two different answers.

The code commented out is the code that I've made. Everything seemed to work fine until I input the name : XX. When I tried to pass that name into the observation, it prints it's not a bird(twice sometimes)  (although it's added to the arraylist). When I tried to type in an actual name, it ran fine. I'm having issues understanding why the else-clause inside the for-loop causes that? The for-loop above the commented out one runs completely fine but I'm not sure why you would need to add a boolean to ensure it's actually on the arraylist?

public void observed(String name) {

```
    boolean birdThere = false; 
    for(Bird bird: this.list) {
        if(bird.getName().equals(name) || bird.getLatinName().equals(name)) {
            bird.addObservation();
            birdThere = true;
        }
    }

    if(!birdThere) {
        System.out.println("Is not a bird!");
    }

    /* //WHY ISN'T THIS WORKING RIGHT???
    for(Bird bird: this.list) {
        if(bird.getName().equals(name) || bird.getLatinName().equals(name)) {
            bird.addObservation();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Is not a bird!");
          }
     }
     */
}
```

When the commented out for-loop is run with the name: "XX," it prints "it's not a bird!"

Answer (score 1):

As I guess (because you didn't paste whole code but just a part of it) the problem is not that list does or doesn't contain the bird with name `XX` but what you do when some given bird from the list does not pass a test in `if` block.

Let's have a look at the original for-loop code: what does for-loop do when some bird doesn't pass a test? Nothing. So if list contains birds with names: `[A, B, C]` and we pass a `XX` to the method, then for-loop will do nothing. But also it tracks (`birdThere` flag) if *any* bird has been identified as `XX`. If not, then it prints an error message (only once).

Now, let's check new implementation. For-loop prints the "Is not a bird!" message every time when some bird doesn't pass a test. With our test list: `[A, B, C]` and `XX` parameter, we would get this message three times because none bird passes the test. What's more, even if some bird passes the test it wouldn't stop the loop so all invalid birds would trigger an error message.